# Spring security multiple provider interruption

Tags: spring-security

I have a spring security configuration with multiple providers and it works fine.
But if one of these providers is not reachable, an exception is raised and the authentication stops.

For example:

```
Login with credentials user/user:
A) - provider1 -> OK (reacheable but no account user/user)
B) - provider2 -> NOT OK (non reachable)
C) - provider 3 -> OK (reachable and has account user/user)
```

It stops at step B, because the provider does not respond. I would like to handle exception thrown at step B and proceed to have a successfull authentication with provider 3.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the API docs for `AuthenticationProvider`, you can optionally return null instead of raising an exception, which will result in the behaviour you want.

So either modify the implementation or use delegation to wrap an existing provider, catch the exception and return null. You should only catch an exception which indicates that there was a system failure, rather than an actual `AuthenticationException` which indicates that the authentication information provided was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be interested, here's my solution:

```
package fr.test.myapp.core.security.ldap;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.ldap.NamingException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticator;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapAuthoritiesPopulator;

@Slf4j
public class CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider extends LdapAuthenticationProvider{

    public CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider(LdapAuthenticator authenticator, LdapAuthoritiesPopulator authoritiesPopulator) {
        super(authenticator, authoritiesPopulator);
    }


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            return super.authenticate(authentication);
        }catch(InternalAuthenticationServiceException ex){
            NamingException ldapAccessFailure = (NamingException)ex.getCause();
            log.warn("Impossible to connect to the LDAP server. This ldap provider is ignored, continues with the next one: Error cause: {}",
ldapAccessFailure.getMessage(),ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```